# Rails, custom exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm following instructions at http://ariejan.net/2011/10/14/rails-3-customized-exception-handling/ and have hit a road block.

I am relatively new to rails, so I'm not sure what I've done right/not-so-right.

The first step was to create class

```
MyApp::ProfileNotFoundError < StandardError
end
```

So I went to app/models and created profile_not_found.rb which contains the following, where (APP) is the name of my app as defined by Rails.application.class.parent_name, but I have hidden from this post for security/privacy.

```
(APP)::ProfileNotFoundError < StandardError
end
```

In app/controllers/application_controller.rb I added

```
rescue_from (APP)::ProfileNotFoundError, :with => :profile_not_found
```

and in my login controller I added

```
raise (APP)::ProfileNotFoundError if @profile.nil?
```

However, when I try to test the code, I get a Routing Error stating

```
uninitialized constant (APP)::BlankUsernameError
```

In my opinion, this suggests that I did something wrong pertaining to the class creation, but the tutorial is so vague I can't figure it out.  Any pointers?

I'm running Rails 3.0.20 & Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 x86_64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the `class` keyword in your class definition?

```
class MyApp::ProfileNotFoundError < StandardError
end
```

Secondly, you'll have to `require` your `exceptions` where you're using it. This is probably the problem you're encountering with the `uninitialized constant` error. To do this you will probably have to wrap it in a module:

```
module Exceptions
  class MyApp::ProfileNotFoundError < StandardError
  end
end
```

Also, you should put your error classes in a different directory than `/models`. This directory should be explicitly for your models. Maybe make one like `/errors`.

Comment: 'class' was in there, for sure, but I think 'include' fixed it!  Thank you.  Sage advice with the /errors directory, I appreciate it.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon- 'include' actually broke it in a different way. When I use 'include (APP)::ProfileNotFoundError', I get 'wrong argument type Class (expected Module)'. I tried changing it to 'include ProfileNotFoundError' and I get 'Expected .../app/errors/profile_not_found_error.rb to define ProfileNotFoundError'. The strange thing is, if I remove 'include' and try it, I get the very same error with the difference being that if I hit refresh it will load the page and the error functions as intended.  I just didn't get the error before because it seems to only happen on server init.

Comment: @Crash See updated. Wrap it in a module. Also note -- you should probably use `require exceptions` instead of the include you were using before.

Comment: It seems this one works- the answer was somewhere in the middle.  'require' returns an error 'cant convert module to string' or something like that.  'include MyApp::ProfileNotFoundError' does work, but you do still have to wrap it into 'module Exceptions ... end'.  Thanks a million!